# How to properly do aliasing in correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

For the following subquery:

```
;WITH results as (
    SELECT 'DAL' as team, 2010 as season, 7 as wins union
    SELECT 'DAL' as team, 2011 as season, 11 as wins union
    SELECT 'DAL' as team, 2012 as season, 11 as wins union
    SELECT 'NE' as team, 2012 as season, 15 as wins union
    SELECT 'DET' as team, 2010 as season, 6 as wins
)

SELECT team, wins, season,
    wins - (select max(wins) from results as r where r.season=results.season) difference_from_best_subquery
FROM results;
```

What is the proper way to alias the results so its clear that you want to pass "this" value into the results? The above works, but I'd hope that I could do something a bit more readable (to myself) such as:

```
SELET MAX(wins) FROM table WHERE wins=$this.wins
```

What's the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, I would just use `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT team, wins, season,
    MAX(wins) OVER (PARTITION BY season) - wins AS diff_from_best
FROM results;
```

Another way to avoid the correlated subquery would be to use a join approach to a subquery which finds the max wins for each season:

```sql
SELECT
    r1.team,
    r1.wins,
    r1.season,
    r2.max_wins - r1.wins AS diff_from_best
FROM results r1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT season, MAX(wins) AS max_wins
    FROM results
    GROUP BY season
) r2
    ON r2.season = r1.season;
```

Comment: thanks for that. Is a window function always preferable to a subquery, or is it ever possible that a subquery could perform better?

Comment: Good question.  The actual _best_ answer here is that the most important thing is probably having an index on `(season, wins)`, which would speed up either the analytic functions approach, the correlated subquery, or the join.  They are all probably going to have (somewhat) similar execution plans.